# Set Javascript variable every n sec. When it's changed also create a json array of variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My variable of numbers updates every one second with mathrandom to some numbers like "14323121" I want to also every seccond save these to an array for say the latest 10 or so.

```
function EveryOneSec() {
    var numbers = math.Random(); // I want to create an array from this...
setTimeOut(EveryOneSec, 1000);
};
```

To bind "numbers" to an array: (Referencing to var numbers above) I want to create an array like below for say the 10 last updates?

```
{"numbers":["2021030213","32454253"]} // For Reigel..
//doesnt have to be key value pairs. just need the value in legit json.
```

Comment: you have bad JSON, may of something like this `{"numbers":["2021030213","32454253"]}` ? that would be valid..

Comment: I said its not real data just an example :P but yes it would have ot be valid I was asking how to go about setting it to an array :)

Comment: Then please give some replica of real code.Otherwise its difficult to understand ur problem.

Comment: Made it a bit clearer (I want to create the JSON array from my "var numbers")

Comment: @Kai I dont understand? The array does not exist. I want to create the array dynamically. After the page loads and starts creating the numbers I then want to bind each of them to the array for use elsewhere.

Comment: I mean, instead of creating JSON array, you can create an regular array. I think u do NOT need to use JSON for this purpose.

Comment: Ah, No I would like to expose it and pull on it in another location when it is available also ^^.

Comment: Why exactly do the random numbers have to be created at intervals?

Comment: It will be the time rather than random numbers was just for example purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong with the your approach? Just setup your variables outside of the function that is repeated and then [JSON encode it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/json).

```
var numbers = [];
var jsonString = "";

function EveryOneSec() {
  numbers.push(Math.random());
  jsonString = JSON.stringify({'numbers': numbers});
  setTimeout(EveryOneSec, 1000);
}
```

However, I think your task might be an excellent opportunity to use a [custom event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/)! You tagged your question jQuery, so you should check out its [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method. Of course there are many [tutorials](http://dailyjs.com/2009/11/14/jquery-custom-events/) on the topic.

```
var numbers = [];
var aPlaceholder = document.createElement("div");
aPlaceholder.bind("arrayUpdatedEvent", {'numbers': numbers}, arrayUpdatedHandler);

function arrayUpdatedHandler(event) {
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(event.data);
  // do something with your JSON
}

function EveryOneSec() {
  // add number to array
  numbers.push(Math.random());
  // trigger custom event
  aPlaceholder.trigger("arrayUpdatedEvent");
}

// call every 1 second, store in var to be able to cancel it later
var myInterval = setInterval(EveryOneSec, 1000);
```

As you can see, there's a lot more code here. However, introducing a custom event gives you a lot of power, as now you have decoupled the the variable updating from the JSON creation. Furthermore, you can add additional listeners, perhaps to also log the updated array, and to insert additional steps between array update and JSON creation. For instance, `EveryOneSec()` could trigger a different event, `verifyArrayEvent`, and only if the array validates does it trigger `arrayUpdatedEvent`.

**Update:** From the comments to the question it looks like Ozaki isn't clear that they can access a previously defined variable within their timer function. By defining a variable outside of a function and then referencing it inside of the function *without using var*, which would create a new, local variable, you are creating a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) where what you do to the variable inside of the function will be available outside of it. As you probably noticed, I used this technique in both my examples.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>S.O. 3163764</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // dump() borrowed from http://www.openjs.com/scripts/others/dump_function_php_print_r.php
    const REPEAT = 3 * 1000; // ms
    const TO_KEEP = 10; // numbers to be kept
    var gObject = { 'numbers': [] };

    /**
     * Function : dump()
     * Arguments: The data - array,hash(associative array),object
     *    The level - OPTIONAL
     * Returns  : The textual representation of the array.
     * This function was inspired by the print_r function of PHP.
     * This will accept some data as the argument and return a
     * text that will be a more readable version of the
     * array/hash/object that is given.
     * Docs: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/others/dump_function_php_print_r.php
     */
    function dump(arr,level) {
        var dumped_text = "";
        if(!level) level = 0;

        //The padding given at the beginning of the line.
        var level_padding = "";
        for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

        if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects 
            for(var item in arr) {
                var value = arr[item];

                if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
                    dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
                    dumped_text += dump(value,level+1);
                } else {
                    dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
                }
            }
        } else { //Stings/Chars/Numbers etc.
            dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
        }
        return dumped_text;
    }

    function everyNSec() {
        var number = Math.random(); 
        store(number);
        window.setTimeout(everyNSec, REPEAT);
    };

    function store(aNumber) {
        gObject.numbers.push(aNumber);

        while (gObject.numbers.length > TO_KEEP)
            gObject.numbers.shift();

        $("#dump").html(dump(gObject));
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        everyNSec();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre id="dump">
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tested on chrome 6.0.447.0 dev